# Inserting data 2 times in entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Sorry, it must be a newbie question but i didn't found any solutions and still on that problem for 2 hours now.
I have the following code :

```
foreach (Stock s in queryStocks)
{
  int checkTimeCount;

  checkTimeCount = (from ph in entity.StockPriceHistories
                    where ph.StockStockId == s.StockId
                    orderby ph.StockPriceHistoryDate descending
                    select ph.StockPriceHistoryDate).Count();
  if (checkTimeCount != 0)
  {
    var checkTimeStock = (from ph in entity.StockPriceHistories
                          where ph.StockStockId == s.StockId
                          orderby ph.StockPriceHistoryDate descending
                          select ph.StockPriceHistoryDate).First();

    string checkTimeStringStock = checkTimeStock.ToShortDateString();

    if (dateNow != checkTimeStringStock)
    {
      StockPriceHistory ph = new StockPriceHistory();
      ph.StockPriceHistoryDate = DateTime.Now;
      ph.StockStockId = s.StockId;
      ph.Value = s.Value;
      entity.StockPriceHistories.Add(ph);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    StockPriceHistory ph = new StockPriceHistory();
    ph.StockPriceHistoryDate = DateTime.Now;
    ph.StockStockId = s.StockId;
    ph.Value = s.Value;
    entity.StockPriceHistories.Add(ph);
  }

}


                // Submit the changes to the database.
                #region SaveChangesDB
                try
                {
                    entity.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch
                {
                // Provide for exceptions.
                }
                #endregion
```

This one insert ph(StockPriceHistory model) twice each time. I want only one to be inserted... i really don't understand why. Made me crazy!

Thanks in advance and sorry again for this noob question and my bad english,

Adrien

**EDIT** after comment 1 :
 [image: queryStock debug screen]

I can't see duplicates here, or maybe i'm missing something ? First is Stock with stockid 1 and second is the stock with stockid 2.
here's is the queryStocks if it can help : 
var queryStocks = from s in entity.Stocks select s; // Get all stocks in DB

Thanks for yours fast answers

**EDIT 2 :** 
Insert Result & date format

[image: Insert]

Date format : "18/02/2016" for each (dateNow & checkTimeStringStock)

**EDIT 3 :**

[image: count]

How is that possible that this query return 2 results from the table on the EDIT 2 screenshot ?

**EDIT 4 :** My bad, count is ok as i'm in a foreach

Comment: Could there be duplicates in `queryStocks`?

Comment: You should step through it and see where it is inserted twice.. otherwise I'd go with @stuartd that there must be duplicates..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i m still stucked, edited my post to add some informations

Answer (score 0):

That was noob.
This foreach was in an other foreach(Portofolio...), i have 2 portofolio so this result was normal.

```
foreach (Portofolio ord in query)
    {

      ...

        foreach (Stock x in queryStockValue)
        {
```

Now it's ok.